# String Formatting in Python2.7 with result from Net commands

Tags: python-2.7, batch-file, string.format

I created a batch file that writes user names to a file. It works perfectly and cleans up `net user` and writes the user names to a file so it would look like this:

`Administrator            Michael                  Guest

Pianoman                  Billy                    George`

I don't know how many usernames there will be so my question is: how can I clean up this white space between the undetermined number of names since I don't know the length of names I'll be dealing with and thus not know how many spaces there will be.

My python program is supposed to read these names from a file and turn them into a list. I was planning on just using .split(" ") so ideally someone could suggest a way to get the difference down to one space between each name. I already looked at .format method, and it doesn't seem to be up to the task. I'm also open if there is a somewhat readable way (doubtable) to format this in batch.

BTW: I considered simply redirecting the output from `dir /B C:\Users` but this doesn't work in situation.

Comment: If the user names do not have any spaces in them, you should have not problems using a `FOR /F` command to parse the output of the `NET USERS` command.

Comment: With PyWin32 installed you can get the list of users as `users, total, resume = win32net.NetUserEnum(None, 0, resume)`. Start with `resume = 0`, and repeat until the call returns `resume` as 0. Each `users` list is a dict with a "name" key. You can merge these items into a complete list of users with a comprehension such as `user_list += [u['name'] for u in users]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html) without `sep` argument:

> ```
> string.split(s[, sep[, maxsplit]])
> ```
>
> Return a list of the words of the string `s`. If the optional second
>   argument `sep` is absent or `None`, the words are separated by
>   arbitrary strings of whitespace characters (space, tab, newline,
>   return, formfeed). If the second argument `sep` is present and not
>   `None`, it specifies a string to be used as the word separator. The
>   returned list will then have one more item than the number of
>   non-overlapping occurrences of the separator in the string. If
>   `maxsplit` is given, at most `maxsplit` number of splits occur, and
>   the remainder of the string is returned as the final element of the
>   list (thus, the list will have at most `maxsplit+1` elements). If
>   `maxsplit` is not specified or `-1`, then there is no limit on the
>   number of splits (all possible splits are made).
>
> The behavior of split on an empty string depends on the value of
>   `sep`. If `sep` is not specified, or specified as `None`, the result
>   will be an empty list. If `sep` is specified as any string, the result
>   will be a list containing one element which is an empty string.

**Example**:

```
>>> x='Administrator            CLIENT1                  Guest'
>>> x.split(' ')
['Administrator', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'CLIENT1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','Guest']
>>> x.split()
['Administrator', 'CLIENT1', 'Guest']
>>>
```

Another approach:

```
>>> import string
>>> x='Administrator            CLIENT1                  Guest'
>>> string.split(x,' ')
['Administrator', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'CLIENT1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','Guest']
>>> string.split(x)
['Administrator', 'CLIENT1', 'Guest']
>>>
```